# How append img in bold with append jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, image, append

> This is my code and it doesn't work. Plese, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('#ramka').append("<b><img src="rat.png"></img></b>");
```

Comment: You're using the same quotes for your file and your string. The `append()` gets evaluated as `"<b><img src="`, and then throws a syntax error after that.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code : *$('#ramka').append("`<b><img src='rat.png'></img></b>`");*

eg: **"`<b class='main'>Main</b>`"**

```js
$('#ramka').append("<b><img src='https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1018/805106121_ab84d1a216_b.jpg'></img></b>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ramka"></div>
```

Comment: Strings that require inner quoting must use double outside and single inside.

var html = "<div id='my-id'></div>";